# Roll back Update or delete data Through Flashback query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have done some changes and commited but i want to roll back those changes through Flashback query.

Can you please help me how to do this?

I am using Oracle 11g Version.

From below tables i have deleted the data..Now i want to revert back those records..

Customer,
Address,
Employee,
Alignemnt

Many Thanks for your help.

Sunitha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things,

**1.Flashback by SCN**

```
SELECT column_list
FROM table_name
AS OF SCN scn_number;
```

**2.Flashback by TIMESTAMP**

```
SELECT column_list
FROM table_name
AS OF TIMESTAMP TO_TIMESTAMP('the timestamp value');
```

To get current_scn and systimestamp, query :

```
SELECT current_scn, SYSTIMESTAMP
FROM v$database;
```

**Update** Example as requested by OP.

To flashback the table to the old scn, use **`FLASHBACK TABLE..TO SCN`** clause.

```
SQL> DROP TABLE string_ex PURGE;

Table dropped.

SQL> CREATE TABLE string_ex (sl_ps_code VARCHAR2(20) );

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO string_ex (sl_ps_code) VALUES ('AR14ASM0002');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO string_ex (sl_ps_code) VALUES ('AR14SFT0018');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO string_ex (sl_ps_code) VALUES ('AR14SFT0019');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO string_ex (sl_ps_code) VALUES ('AR14SFT0062');

1 row created.

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL> SELECT current_scn, SYSTIMESTAMP FROM v$database;

         CURRENT_SCN SYSTIMESTAMP
-------------------- --------------------------------------------
      13818123201277 29-OCT-14 03.02.17.419000 PM +05:30

SQL> SELECT current_scn, SYSTIMESTAMP FROM v$database;

         CURRENT_SCN SYSTIMESTAMP
-------------------- --------------------------------------------
      13818123201280 29-OCT-14 03.02.22.785000 PM +05:30

SQL> SELECT current_scn, SYSTIMESTAMP FROM v$database;

         CURRENT_SCN SYSTIMESTAMP
-------------------- --------------------------------------------
      13818123201282 29-OCT-14 03.02.26.781000 PM +05:30

SQL> SELECT * FROM string_ex;

SL_PS_CODE
---------------
AR14ASM0002
AR14SFT0018
AR14SFT0019
AR14SFT0062

SQL>
```

**I have four rows in the table**.

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE string_ex ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT;

Table altered.

SQL>
```

**Row movement is required.**

```
SQL> DELETE FROM string_ex WHERE ROWNUM =1;

1 row deleted.

SQL>
SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM string_ex;

SL_PS_CODE
---------------
AR14SFT0018
AR14SFT0019
AR14SFT0062
```

**I deleted a row now and committed the changes.**

```
SQL> FLASHBACK TABLE string_ex TO SCN 13818123201277;

Flashback complete.
```

**Flashback is complete**

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM string_ex;

SL_PS_CODE
---------------
AR14ASM0002
AR14SFT0018
AR14SFT0019
AR14SFT0062

SQL>
```

**I now have my table to old state and the row is back**

Comment: But this will give only count..and how to revert bask those changes..Many thanks for your help

Comment: I have updated my answer. `FLASHBACK TABLE..TO SCN` is the clause you need. See the answer.